# Golf my "pre-golfed" C

Tags: code-golf, c

### Background

For my [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) submissions in C, I need a processing tool. Like in many other languages, whitespace is mostly irrelevant in C source (but not always!) -- still makes the code much more comprehensible for humans. A fully golfed C program that doesn't contain a single redundant whitespace often is barely readable.

Therefore, I like to write my code in C for a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) submission including whitespace and sometimes comments, so the program keeps a comprehensible structure while writing. The last step is to remove all comments and redundant whitespace. This is a tedious and mindless task which really should be done by <strike>an intern</strike> a computer program.

### Task

Write a program or function that eliminates comments and redundant whitespace from some "pre-golfed" C source according to the following rules:

- A `\` (backslash) as the very last character in a line is a *line continuation*. If you find this, you must treat the following line as part of the same *logical line* (you could for example remove the `\` and the following `\n` (newline) completely before doing anything else)
- Comments will only use the one-line format, starting with `//`. So to remove them, you ignore the rest of the logical line wherever you encounter `//` outside a *string literal* (see below).
- Whitespace characters are  (space), `\t` (tab) and `\n` (newline, so here the end of a logical line).
- When you find a sequence of whitespace, examine the non-whitespace characters surrounding it. If

  - both of them are alphanumeric or underscore (range `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or
  - both are `+` or
  - both are `-` or
  - the preceeding one is `/` and the following one is `*`

  then replace the sequence with a single space () character.

  Otherwise, eliminate the sequence completely.

  This rule has *some exceptions*:

  - *Preprocessor directives* must appear on their own lines in your output. A preprocessor directive is a line starting with `#`.
  - Inside a *string literal* or *character literal*, you shouldn't remove any whitespace.  Any `"` (double-quote) / `'` (single-quote) that isn't directly preceeded by an odd number of backslashes (`\`) starts or ends a *string literal* / *character literal*. You're guaranteed that string and character literals end on the same line they started. *string literals* and *character literals* cannot be nested, so a `'` inside a *string literal*, as well as a `"` inside a *character literal* don't have any special meaning.

#### I/O specification

Input and output must be either character sequences (strings) including newline characters or arrays/lists of strings that don't contain newline characters. If you choose to use arrays/lists, each element represents a line, so the newlines are *implicit* after each element.

You may assume the input is a valid C program source code. This also means it only contains printable ASCII characters, tabs and newlines. Undefined behavior on malformed input is allowed.

**Leading and trailing whitespace / empty lines** are **not allowed**.

#### Test cases

1. input

   ```
   main() {
       printf("Hello, World!"); // hi
   }
   ```

   output

   ```
   main(){printf("Hello, World!");}
   ```
2. input

   ```
   #define max(x, y) \
       x > y ? x : y
   #define I(x) scanf("%d", &x)
   a;
   b; // just a needless comment, \
           because we can!
   main()
   {
       I(a);
       I(b);
       printf("\" max \": %d\n", max(a, b));
   }
   ```

   output

   ```
   #define max(x,y)x>y?x:y
   #define I(x)scanf("%d",&x)
   a;b;main(){I(a);I(b);printf("\" max \": %d\n",max(a,b));}
   ```
3. input

   ```
   x[10];*c;i;
   main()
   {
       int _e;
       for(; scanf("%d", &x) > 0 && ++_e;);
       for(c = x + _e; c --> x; i = 100 / *x, printf("%d ", i - --_e));
   }
   ```

   output

   ```
   x[10];*c;i;main(){int _e;for(;scanf("%d",&x)>0&&++_e;);for(c=x+_e;c-->x;i=100/ *x,printf("%d ",i- --_e));}
   ```
4. input

   ```
   x;
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
       puts("hello // there");
   }
   ```

   output

   ```
   x;
   #include<stdio.h>
   int main(){puts("hello // there");}
   ```
5. input (a real-world example)

   ```
   // often used functions/keywords:
   #define P printf(
   #define A case
   #define B break

   // loops for copying rows upwards/downwards are similar -> macro
   #define L(i, e, t, f, s) \
           for (o=i; o e;){ strcpy(l[o t], l[o f]); c[o t]=c[s o]; }

   // range check for rows/columns is similar -> macro
   #define R(m,o) { return b<1|b>m ? m o : b; }

   // checking for numerical input is needed twice (move and print command):
   #define N(f) sscanf(f, "%d,%d", &i, &j) || sscanf(f, ",%d", &j)

   // room for 999 rows with each 999 cols (not specified, should be enough)
   // also declare "current line pointers" (*L for data, *C for line length),
   // an input buffer (a) and scratch variables
   r, i, j, o, z, c[999], *C, x=1, y=1;
   char a[999], l[999][999], (*L)[999];

   // move rows down from current cursor position
   D()
   {
       L(r, >y, , -1, --)
       r++ ? strcpy(l[o], l[o-1]+--x), c[o-1]=x, l[o-1][x]=0 : 0;
       c[y++] = strlen(l[o]);
       x=1;
   }

   // move rows up, appending uppermost to current line
   U()
   {
       strcat(*L, l[y]);
       *C = strlen(*L);
       L(y+1, <r, -1, , ++)
       --r;
       *l[r] = c[r] = 0;
   }

   // normalize positions, treat 0 as max
   X(b) R(c[y-1], +1)
   Y(b) R(r, )

   main()
   {
       for(;;) // forever
       {
           // initialize z as current line index, the current line pointers,
           // i and j for default values of positioning
           z = i = y;
           L = l + --z;
           C = c + z;
           j = x;

           // prompt:
           !r || y/r && x > *C
               ? P "end> ")
               : P "%d,%d> ", y, x);

           // read a line of input (using scanf so we don't need an include)
           scanf("%[^\n]%*c", a)

               // no command arguments -> make check easier:
               ? a[2] *= !!a[1],

               // numerical input -> have move command:
               // calculate new coordinates, checking for "relative"
               N(a)
                   ? y = Y(i + (i<0 | *a=='+') * y)
                       , x = X(j + (j<0 || strchr(a+1, '+')) * x)
                   :0

               // check for empty input, read single newline
               // and perform <return> command:
               : ( *a = D(), scanf("%*c") );

           switch(*a)
           {
               A 'e':
                   y = r;
                   x = c[r-1] + 1;
                   B;

               A 'b':
                   y = 1;
                   x = 1;
                   B;

               A 'L':
                   for(o = y-4; ++o < y+2;)
                       o<0 ^ o<r && P "%c%s\n", o^z ? ' ' : '>', l[o]);
                   for(o = x+1; --o;)
                       P " ");
                   P "^\n");
                   B;

               A 'l':
                   puts(*L);
                   B;

               A 'p':
                   i = 1;
                   j = 0;
                   N(a+2);
                   for(o = Y(i)-1; o<Y(j); ++o)
                       puts(l[o]);
                   B;

               A 'A':
                   y = r++;
                   strcpy(l[y], a+2);
                   x = c[y] = strlen(a+2);
                   ++x;
                   ++y;
                   B;

               A 'i':
                   D();
                   --y;
                   x=X(0);
                   // Commands i and r are very similar -> fall through
                   // from i to r after moving rows down and setting
                   // position at end of line:

               A 'r':
                   strcpy(*L+x-1, a+2);
                   *C = strlen(*L);
                   x = 1;
                   ++y > r && ++r;
                   B;

               A 'I':
                   o = strlen(a+2);
                   memmove(*L+x+o-1, *L+x-1, *C-x+1);
                   *C += o;
                   memcpy(*L+x-1, a+2, o);
                   x += o;
                   B;

               A 'd':
                   **L ? **L = *C = 0, x = 1 : U();
                   y = y>r ? r : y;
                   B;

               A 'j':
                   y<r && U();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   output

   ```
   #define P printf(
   #define A case
   #define B break
   #define L(i,e,t,f,s)for(o=i;o e;){strcpy(l[o t],l[o f]);c[o t]=c[s o];}
   #define R(m,o){return b<1|b>m?m o:b;}
   #define N(f)sscanf(f,"%d,%d",&i,&j)||sscanf(f,",%d",&j)
   r,i,j,o,z,c[999],*C,x=1,y=1;char a[999],l[999][999],(*L)[999];D(){L(r,>y,,-1,--)r++?strcpy(l[o],l[o-1]+--x),c[o-1]=x,l[o-1][x]=0:0;c[y++]=strlen(l[o]);x=1;}U(){strcat(*L,l[y]);*C=strlen(*L);L(y+1,<r,-1,,++)--r;*l[r]=c[r]=0;}X(b)R(c[y-1],+1)Y(b)R(r,)main(){for(;;){z=i=y;L=l+--z;C=c+z;j=x;!r||y/r&&x>*C?P"end> "):P"%d,%d> ",y,x);scanf("%[^\n]%*c",a)?a[2]*=!!a[1],N(a)?y=Y(i+(i<0|*a=='+')*y),x=X(j+(j<0||strchr(a+1,'+'))*x):0:(*a=D(),scanf("%*c"));switch(*a){A'e':y=r;x=c[r-1]+1;B;A'b':y=1;x=1;B;A'L':for(o=y-4;++o<y+2;)o<0^o<r&&P"%c%s\n",o^z?' ':'>',l[o]);for(o=x+1;--o;)P" ");P"^\n");B;A'l':puts(*L);B;A'p':i=1;j=0;N(a+2);for(o=Y(i)-1;o<Y(j);++o)puts(l[o]);B;A'A':y=r++;strcpy(l[y],a+2);x=c[y]=strlen(a+2);++x;++y;B;A'i':D();--y;x=X(0);A'r':strcpy(*L+x-1,a+2);*C=strlen(*L);x=1;++y>r&&++r;B;A'I':o=strlen(a+2);memmove(*L+x+o-1,*L+x-1,*C-x+1);*C+=o;memcpy(*L+x-1,a+2,o);x+=o;B;A'd':**L?**L=*C=0,x=1:U();y=y>r?r:y;B;A'j':y<r&&U();}}}
   ```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest (in bytes) valid answer wins.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48326/remove-single-line-and-multiline-comments-from-string), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60230/remove-whitespace-from-a-java-program)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68477/discussion-between-dlosc-and-felix-palmen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>148</s> <s>135</s> <s>133</s> 138 bytes

```
aRM"\
"R`("|').*?(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\1`{lPBaC:++i+191}R[`//.*``#.*`{X*aJw.`(?=`}.')M[A`\w`RL2"++""--""/*"]w`¶+`'·C(192+,#l)][x_WR'¶{aRw'·}xnsl]
```

Bytes are counted in [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), so `¶` and `·` are one byte each. Note that this expects the C code as a single command-line argument, which (on an actual command line) would require the use of copious escape sequences. It's much easier at [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7baoNAEIbvfYrJSuOuq67mLjEH2tyE0kDwpgUVVzyQha2GJEWL9bXS@7yY3QZ6@C@GYWb@75@DOAxDGmxRpKGAY/RhEMdc4dV8FEUER0rEjDzeyd1Dup5RKqg39fog5Iw5Jue6Kt2LmT42DserBe8dg2zDex41PHiaIEoRsm2EmInihl8vlBvXzzX2phNq6ZLEYZs8B8b10qVBozZ9W51kPAzDu6/posrkW17A/HTORe3sl5qeF6WoCthBpMGPDkdRnUv8u9wA2hRS1pY6auqjzEeMIa0NPTf2zcwXvvaaigoTYAz2AmYG0bobTWEgKfxbX9ZH7P9LOWVpVWJ0lyMLxi2BJbgwHgOlykD@LBksoAX6jYEMbHsJrQ9CDT3XBQZma6nfFUVFG4okwFZHSUEUov8C)

### Explanation of slightly ungolfed version

The code does a bunch of replacement operations, with a couple tricks.

#### Backslash continuations

We `RM` all occurrences of the literal string

```
"\
"
```

that is, backslash followed by newline.

#### String and character literals

We use a regex replacement with a callback function:

```
`("|').*?(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\1`

{
 lPBa
 C(++i + 191)
}
```

The regex matches a single or double quote, followed by a non-greedy `.*?` that matches 0 or more characters, as few as possible. We have a negative lookbehind to ensure that the previous character was not a backslash; then we match an even number of backslashes followed by the opening delimiter again.

The callback function takes the string/character literal and pushes it to the back of the list `l`. It then returns a character starting with character code 192 (`À`) and increasing with each literal replaced. Thus, code is transformed like so:

```
printf("%c", '\'');

printf(À, Á);
```

These replacement characters are guaranteed not to occur in the source code, which means we can unambiguously back-substitute them later.

#### Comments

```
`//.*`

x
```

The regex matches `//` plus everything up to the newline and replaces with `x` (preset to the empty string).

#### Preprocessor directives

```
`#.*`

_WR'¶
```

Wraps runs of non-newline characters starting with a pound sign in `¶`.

#### Spaces that should not be eliminated

```
{
 (
  X*a J w.`(?=`
 ) . ')
}
M
[
 A`\w` RL 2
 "++"
 "--"
 "/*"
]

{
 a R w '·
}
```

There's a lot going on here. The first part generates this list of regexes to replace:

```
[
 `(?a)\w\s+(?=(?a)\w)`  Whitespace surrounded by [a-zA-Z_]
 `\+\s+(?=\+)`          Whitespace surrounded by +
 `\-\s+(?=\-)`          Whitespace surrounded by -
 `\/\s+(?=\*)`          Whitespace surrounded by / *
]
```

Note the use of lookaheads to match, for example, just the `e`  in `define P printf`. That way this match doesn't consume the `P`, which means the next match can use it.

We generate this list of regexes by mapping a function to a list, where the list contains

```
[
 [`(?a)\w` `(?a)\w`]
 "++"
 "--"
 "/*"
]
```

and the function does this to each element:

```
(X*aJw.`(?=`).')
 X*a              Map unary X to elements/chars a: converts to regex, escaping as needed
                  Regexes like `\w` stay unchanged; strings like "+" become `\+`
    J             Join the resulting list on:
     w             Preset variable for `\s+`
      .`(?=`       plus the beginning of the lookahead syntax
(           ).')  Concatenate the closing paren of the lookahead
```

Once we have our regexes, we replace their occurrences with this callback function:

```
{aRw'·}
```

which replaces the run of whitespace in each match with `·`.

#### Whitespace elimination and cleanup

```
[w `¶+` '·]

[x n s]
```

Three successive replacements substitute remaining runs of whitespace (`w`) for empty string (`x`), runs of `¶` for newline, and `·` for space.

#### Back-substitution of string and character literals

```
C(192+,#l)

l
```

We construct a list of all the characters we used as substitutions for literals by taking `192 + range(len(l))` and converting to characters. We then can replace each of these with its associated literal in `l`.

And that's it! The resulting string is autoprinted.

Comment: Great, I'm impressed (+1)! Including a `//` inside a string literal is definitely a good idea for a test case, I'll add one tomorrow.

Comment: Uhm ... now I found a [subtle bug](https://tio.run/##RU1Na4NAFLz7K15XqvvhZ26pTaTNrTQQPBVcccUoXbBWkoILxr/V3PPH7GsvncPwmJk3M@hhWapMUXJxWcBTmj7eScmoRDAuYzV1h@dq9yCEFvE6nrNcSWldwjDgStlI0xuvXsZA0XSj5sBl@/xJyVFlrysiBCG@T0jISTG6t2/3dt3ReL0Snt2xIjdlgOJUZehdZ9Ofu2JZFpPHUZHwOtGJZR@bVvcNHGA46f6rpdZHpXvKIAzhXVuTBQg0oGySv7v9PNEEznXVt5TcH4kHjmGwhQgcB4TAGPsP1rABA@L3GWrw/S2YBDSKcRRBCNx4OIwtOIZFGnzMlA3DhvkH) here as well...

Comment: I'm going to pick a winner after 14 days (end of next week) and your solution would be the first candidate **if** you find time to fix this bug. Right now, you have the lowest score :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Fixed!

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>327</s> <s>360</s> <s>418</s> 394 bytes

```hs
g.(m.w.r.r=<<).lines.f
n:c:z="\n#_0123456789"++['A'..'Z']++['a'..'z']
(!)x=elem x
f('\\':'\n':a)=f a
f(a:b)=a:f b
f a=a
m('#':a)=c:a++[n]
m a=a
g(a:'#':b)=a:[n|a/=n]++c:g b
g(a:b)=a:g b
g a=a
s=span(!" \t")
r=reverse.snd.s
l n(a:b)d|a==d,n=a:w(snd$s b)|1>0=a:l(not$n&&a=='\\')b d
w('/':'/':_)=[]
w(a:b)|a!"\"'"=a:l(1>0)b a|(p,q:u)<-s b=a:[' '|p>"",a!z&&q!z||[a,q]!words"++ -- /*"]++w(q:u)
w a=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVFtT8MgEP7Or6DMDHAbc76Lw8S/4dqYa0u7xZZ1Zdpl1r9uPZr4geTueeMOtuA/bFUNWxMPpRK16lSrWrNeS1XtnPWqIE5n@mxY7CbvV6vrm9u7@4fHJzabbfgrV4q/8STUEOozT4iI5MnYytb0RArB45hrHjuuQZqCAkKgU2lAFzQlCBggteCTkc80YJRLSD3iJUoDM8o3roelcXhXpku0lv85YzPqvfENOBExGh@ZJK1p7ZdtvVXe5cqTirrRk/dgTD536O0EUheeprJfvVwhUAm3P1646RQlYXSZ0px0gi9xCTzv0mwS7ENMDxGLGWejC90ohV4084P@lOsFZoahOeV988LYHKLzdHqIzn2/gfkhibp9m3t8RLpY0OUlw7U6EZykC6sMNewcNXTnjraF7Ei3w@mZTHJb4J/QYr@nKbQkiIQk3@TnNysqKP2wyJrmDw)

This was a lot of fun to write! First the `f` function comes through and removes all the backslashes at the end of lines then `lines` breaks it into a list of strings at the newlines. Then we map a bunch of functions onto the lines and concatenate them all back together. Those functions: strip whitespace from the left (`t`) and from the right (`r.t.r` where `r` is `reverse`); remove whitespace from the middle, ignoring string and character literals as well as removing comments (`w`); and finally adds a newline character to the end if the line starts with a #. After all the lines are concatenated back together `g` looks for # characters and ensures they are preceded by a newline.

`w` is a little complex so I'll explain it further. First I check for "//" since in `w` I know I'm not in a string literal I know this is a comment so I drop the rest of the line. Next I check if the head is a delimiter for a string or character literal. If it is I prepend it and pass the baton to `l` which runs through the characters, tracking the "escape" state with `n` which will be true if there have been an even number of consecutive slashes. When `l` detects a delimiter and isn't in the escape state it passes the baton back to `w`, trimming to eliminate whitespace after the literal because `w` expects the first character to not be whitespace. When `w` doesn't find a delimiter it uses span to look for whitespace in the tail. If there's any it checks if the characters around it are cannot be brought into contact and inserts a space if so. Then it recurs after the whitespace is ended. If there was no whitespace no space is inserted and it moves on anyway.

EDIT: Thanks a lot to @DLosc for pointing out a bug in my program that actually led to a way for me to shorten it as well! Hooray for pattern matching!

EDIT2: I'm an idiot who didn't finish reading the spec! Thanks again DLosc for pointing that out!

EDIT3: Just noticed some annoying type reduction thing that turned `e=elem` into `Char->[Char]->Bool` for some reason, thus breaking on `e[a,q]`. I had to add a type signature to force it to be correct.  Does anyone know how I could fix that? I've never had this problem in Haskell before. [TIO](https://tio.run/##rVffb6NIEn7nr6hhNwYMTuzRvYwdHM3M3cNJ0eq00upmzvHstqGJcYBmuiH@Ec@/vrmvG9txYnKbh7NkA9VUddVXVV@150zd8Sx7nIc3j25@vjyX55X@hpeX3nmWFlydJxYPecZzK3Gdmxtn6NwUzpB5YUIMIjaceSEbJjSzIAiZlbvOT2bdXHzfvilsKzdLMpT8nkvFrU3o/O4MJ07fOT93PjhT3584H/X9f5p7pu83ztRSofsH/8Omm8r2rCqMpSj/PU8zTsrKqDC7x1sWhnGnU8CNpVvRzNsOxn08ZG4hqp@LTgfr2nNvRrG1dJ0LxIDv7144mVq9Hv2fPve9f0gpJEWsVjymOZecZtw8UVo5iphSdY4VTsMhfZ4zSb0xTfTNVN99EiKDezqkLSdm39iObaJANHCdbd0y@D6svcueKllBimZYnTjkbMuxbQdCTqBFm06H03faBHzCgu/Tn5dCxsr2fUKgF117CniXrjZjLXVOHnOWFhRSWlRcsqii@ePFBYmk4gWZMJK6iKpUFOrijq@NsaH1U8wTlAb9i0oJxcQ9SD4ieqR3//iJZpKzO8uCzUyIUlGiARLlOi1uSYqlorpcMhi9iMWyMHfEgJtK8zRrAMpZJMXB4rWbBsQDqgJKAlIe3Vh7/LVpV4TpiATxkfdAqpJRuXaziaBqGpC@JlNvRJERhNFEkZiO6IdxT7LillM059GdsaSdu4hEVueFolS97tGvbh4Ijx5I8qqWBc0uB9vZOKcryuHIkGb7HYxtHbc2X6ASZBqxDMiXdaV3KDiPAXi1TCNObi7ukc4ibiAGZnmOJ@8J/F/cxCOlIlYkLqCwz@LgLLYD6gCgzsKj7fZ4dbe28JpghciNGx8@fGjSsEyrOXEWzY0IcSvS3UOq5FGapDwG2HNRZzFKmngh6tu5py2xTAmKeZTprNlRLSWHt5o4qBSmqJRNbvfa7BazigXU/WwezDsZL26ruRcYU8UOi1mdJBy5ZJ4BQEWSVXDsnsmUzTKuLBkQglwEJAIUOvIJn6facECrcBDQOhyMrEg3GNstZea6e4A7nrkdGTAM0gYEXYOUSGCzDwRXBV9LoVLdBNbfXc96MBV37cKL8TqggHrYstfzjFii066OKq@pu95g6vd6K0/7qh/C1V48WU3DPqqkPzLq0WTt@1P0IywAG2PBa5ZWOqgfLzyuy4BYWfIi1oVV407mQlVUCTrOhfXbwW/tGqsAgfZgvTeOnBz2BDqjXYhrH6FdyibEgHy/CbLXkzu1bCK1t1Fz6e8dLITMWZZu@AE5hZYFFVTUBw2ig1bWF3fmoXkQMWCA7YFnfW1E2A9lqonp4DUKxh2NPIJt3OohYsQPh@bHQlpgp2bXjd7kWTGmRcwBejXn1FqkwTNLpu4WTc3yhNVZherLag7CSA4hAfGD0kZTKL7r0UF0jceMNO9unoQa5gjCI9ECohUq8Wj/EiVYVsOD6J3U3by@kNTp0IrGSJd1PHmuwMQ2amBMtvdsYagXDDFgCX2B/vCeb4WcxJgaBgvE1jSgWytdToY9CP295GiNwqkMRTV9GmV1zJ82a4jGPpt8uymmZ90ImzHPeuaLKYs9j4Hkb8GARaUaQr3bUy9nKuVy@CI8Nnk/pW5I796xCYrl1PALNoXNOUOPmEbZbTl8qYTXozpjFUdYS7yF2ZYWeESpPqNqW3K8ld5z@5mFX8BP1sszwBWtkc6vboocu@lln7bU1acP3/GoS@tTBf1BVqD0xV1opYVW2po2nUuX6QbU2lp9dao@7J9g8TTCOIpo3SASNInWac1MvIYVXmiaacMlVHM0vZlm43b0huQiLjgNPgwOyUfaPTquL4WpEs3d7hFQD8/sfCSHO8OTqDSGcnQiXjVMA7oAUIPT9U8j66X12SvWB@3W32b0usWoJiihCaD3txF4UtAlrf33o/aEC@T4G35NP@sOjc4UTsmYZ982KCEc6YCwM3bMkNhTdNtuK38wAsGIV/aBaTDCqTrk6NO2lZZos5ZoUVHqaU78hYGyxUDaDvaiGSIvxWg1//3/gAH95vWAhLj86i48g387IMbvVzBt8fzja7Xp@6f6h5m/xjRr97cp4PXRfG9/z/dXbcL1m5xOW5xGm57q9notBlfhF7ff8jLo4XPDBGo3HqU5qGMSr4/PxgnLMkxZqQ@IbUbM6SrV5xPo41@G1Bx9@DNgDmDmzMer6ni@Hg/H3fglHCYw8/TU0mQ2PAFCtgCxS1L32l/pI007/K2HoTdQBTKE2Wya2vflm5L1zxYfxV@VR85zPdhMFL7Qcezj6X7ugRLaQ/JDEq22XgACFmoNuV2/Jaa4JaYu/gFcmd@wgbffDL0BiO63tuLUbbYeSyhJvPK2yl@0tWtDss/2@GE1vz/@jJKM3arHXlSW/wU)

EDIT4: quick fix for bug @FelixPalmen showed me. I might try to golf it down later when I have some time.

EDIT5: -24 bytes thanks to @Lynn! Thank you! I didn't know you could assign things on the global scope using pattern matching like `n:c:z=...` that's really cool! Also good idea making an operator for `elem` wish I'd thought of that.

Comment: I [squeezed out 24 bytes](https://tio.run/##NVFtT8MgEP7Or6DMDHAbc76Lw8S/4dqYa0u7xZZ1Zdpl1r9uPZr4geTueeMOtuA/bFUNWxMPpRK16lSrWrNeS1XtnPWqIE5n@mxY7CbvV6vrm9u7@4fHJzabbfgrV4q/8STUEOozT4iI5MnYytb0RArB45hrHjuuQZqCAkKgU2lAFzQlCBggteCTkc80YJRLSD3iJUoDM8o3roelcXhXpku0lv85YzPqvfENOBExGh@ZJK1p7ZdtvVXe5cqTirrRk/dgTD536O0EUheeprJfvVwhUAm3P1646RQlYXSZ0px0gi9xCTzv0mwS7ENMDxGLGWejC90ohV4084P@lOsFZoahOeV988LYHKLzdHqIzn2/gfkhibp9m3t8RLpY0OUlw7U6EZykC6sMNewcNXTnjraF7Ei3w@mZTHJb4J/QYr@nKbQkiIQk3@TnNysqKP2wyJrmDw).

Comment: You are running into the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction); defining `e x y=elem x y` (or even `e x=elem x`) solves your problem. (I renamed `e` to an operator, `(!)`.)

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>497</s> <s>494</s> <s>490</s> 489 bytes

Since we're processing C, let's do it *using* C!  Function `f()` takes input from char pointer `p` and outputs to pointer `q`, and assumes that the input is in ASCII:

```c
#define O*q++
#define R (r=*p++)
#define V(c)(isalnum(c)||c==95)
char*p,*q,r,s,t;d(){isspace(r)?g():r==47&&*p==r?c(),g():r==92?e():(O=s=r)==34?b():r==39?O=R,a():r?a():(O=r);}a(){R;d();}b(){((O=R)==34?a:r==92?O=R,b:b)();}c(){while(R-10)p+=r==92;}e(){R-10?s=O=92,O=r,a():h();}j(){(!isspace(R)?r==47&&*p==r?c(),j:(t=r==35,d):j)();}f(){t=*p==35;j();}i(){V(s)&&V(r)||s==47&&r==42||(s==43||s==45)&&r==s&&*p==s?O=32:0;d();}h(){isspace(R)?g():i();}g(){(r==10?t?O=r,j:*p==35?s-10?s=O=r,j:0:h:h)();}
```

We assume that the file is well-formed - string and character literals are closed, and if there's a comment on the final line, there must be a newline to close it.

### Explanation

The pre-golfed version is only slightly more legible, I'm afraid:

```c
#define O *q++=
#define R (r=*p++)
#define V(c)(isalnum(c)||c=='_')
char*p,*q,r,s,t;
d(){isspace(r)?g():r=='/'&&*p==r?c(),g():r=='\\'?e():(O s=r)=='"'?b():r=='\''?O R,a():r?a():(O r);}
a(){R;d();}
b(){((O R)=='"'?a:r=='\\'?O R,b:b)();}
c(){while(R!='\n')p+=r=='\\';}
e(){R!='\n'?s=O'\\',O r,a():h();}
j(){(!isspace(R)?r=='/'&&*p==r?c(),j:(t=r=='#',d):j)();}
f(){t=*p=='#';j();}
i(){V(s)&&V(r)||s=='/'&&r=='*'||(s=='+'||s=='-')&&r==s&&*p==s?O' ':0;d();}
h(){isspace(R)?g():i();}
g(){(r=='\n'?t?O r,j:*p=='#'?s!='\n'?s=O r,j:0:h:h)();}
```

It implements a state machine by tail recursion.  The helper macros and variables are

- **`O`** for **o**utput
- **`R`** to **r**ead input into `r`
- **`V`** to determine **v**alid identifier characters (since `!isalnum('_')`)
- **`p`** and **`q`** - I/O pointers as described
- **`r`** - last character to be **r**ead
- **`s`** - **s**aved recent non-whitespace character
- **`t`** - **t**ag when working on a preprocessor directive

Our states are

- **`a()`** - normal C code
- **`b()`** - string literal
- **`c()`** - comment
- **`d()`** - normal C code, after reading `r`
- **`e()`** - escape sequence
- **`f()`** - initial state (main function)
- **`g()`** - in whitespace
- **`h()`** - in whitespace - dispatch to `g()` or `i()`
- **`i()`** - immediately after whitespace - do we need to insert a space character?
- **`j()`** - initial whitespace - never insert a space character

### Test program

```c
#define DEMO(code)                              \
    do {                                        \
        char in[] = code;                       \
        char out[sizeof in];                    \
        p=in;q=out;f();                         \
        puts("vvvvvvvvvv");                     \
        puts(out);                              \
        puts("^^^^^^^^^^");                     \
    } while (0)

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    DEMO(
         "main() {\n"
         "    printf(\"Hello, World!\"); // hi\n"
         "}\n"
         );
    DEMO(
         "#define max(x, y)                               \\\n"
         "    x > y ? x : y\n"
         "#define I(x) scanf(\"%d\", &x)\n"
         "a;\n"
         "b; // just a needless comment, \\\n"
         "        because we can!\n"
         "main()\n"
         "{\n"
         "    I(a);\n"
         "    I(b);\n"
         "    printf(\"\\\" max \\\": %d\\n\", max(a, b));\n"
         "}\n"
         );
    DEMO(
         "x[10];*c;i;\n"
         "main()\n"
         "{\n"
         "    int _e;\n"
         "    for(; scanf(\"%d\", &x) > 0 && ++_e;);\n"
         "    for(c = x + _e; c --> x; i = 100 / *x, printf(\"%d \", i - --_e));\n"
         "}\n"
         );
    DEMO(
         "// often used functions/keywords:\n"
         "#define P printf(\n"
         "#define A case\n"
         "#define B break\n"
         "\n"
         "// loops for copying rows upwards/downwards are similar -> macro\n"
         "#define L(i, e, t, f, s) \\\n"
         "        for (o=i; o e;){ strcpy(l[o t], l[o f]); c[o t]=c[s o]; }\n"
         "\n"
         "// range check for rows/columns is similar -> macro\n"
         "#define R(m,o) { return b<1|b>m ? m o : b; }\n"
         "\n"
         "// checking for numerical input is needed twice (move and print command):\n"
         "#define N(f) sscanf(f, \"%d,%d\", &i, &j) || sscanf(f, \",%d\", &j)\n"
         "\n"
         "// room for 999 rows with each 999 cols (not specified, should be enough)\n"
         "// also declare \"current line pointers\" (*L for data, *C for line length),\n"
         "// an input buffer (a) and scratch variables\n"
         "r, i, j, o, z, c[999], *C, x=1, y=1;\n"
         "char a[999], l[999][999], (*L)[999];\n"
         "\n"
         "// move rows down from current cursor position\n"
         "D()\n"
         "{\n"
         "    L(r, >y, , -1, --)\n"
         "    r++ ? strcpy(l[o], l[o-1]+--x), c[o-1]=x, l[o-1][x]=0 : 0;\n"
         "    c[y++] = strlen(l[o]);\n"
         "    x=1;\n"
         "}\n"
         "\n"
         "// move rows up, appending uppermost to current line\n"
         "U()\n"
         "{\n"
         "    strcat(*L, l[y]);\n"
         "    *C = strlen(*L);\n"
         "    L(y+1, <r, -1, , ++)\n"
         "    --r;\n"
         "    *l[r] = c[r] = 0;\n"
         "}\n"
         "\n"
         "// normalize positions, treat 0 as max\n"
         "X(b) R(c[y-1], +1)\n"
         "Y(b) R(r, )\n"
         "\n"
         "main()\n"
         "{\n"
         "    for(;;) // forever\n"
         "    {\n"
         "        // initialize z as current line index, the current line pointers,\n"
         "        // i and j for default values of positioning\n"
         "        z = i = y;\n"
         "        L = l + --z;\n"
         "        C = c + z;\n"
         "        j = x;\n"
         "\n"
         "        // prompt:\n"
         "        !r || y/r && x > *C\n"
         "            ? P \"end> \")\n"
         "            : P \"%d,%d> \", y, x);\n"
         "\n"
         "        // read a line of input (using scanf so we don't need an include)\n"
         "        scanf(\"%[^\\n]%*c\", a)\n"
         "\n"
         "            // no command arguments -> make check easier:\n"
         "            ? a[2] *= !!a[1],\n"
         "\n"
         "            // numerical input -> have move command:\n"
         "            // calculate new coordinates, checking for \"relative\"\n"
         "            N(a)\n"
         "                ? y = Y(i + (i<0 | *a=='+') * y)\n"
         "                    , x = X(j + (j<0 || strchr(a+1, '+')) * x)\n"
         "                :0\n"
         "\n"
         "            // check for empty input, read single newline\n"
         "            // and perform <return> command:\n"
         "            : ( *a = D(), scanf(\"%*c\") );\n"
         "\n"
         "        switch(*a)\n"
         "        {\n"
         "            A 'e':\n"
         "                y = r;\n"
         "                x = c[r-1] + 1;\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'b':\n"
         "                y = 1;\n"
         "                x = 1;\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'L':\n"
         "                for(o = y-4; ++o < y+2;)\n"
         "                    o<0 ^ o<r && P \"%c%s\\n\", o^z ? ' ' : '>', l[o]);\n"
         "                for(o = x+1; --o;)\n"
         "                    P \" \");\n"
         "                P \"^\\n\");\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'l':\n"
         "                puts(*L);\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'p':\n"
         "                i = 1;\n"
         "                j = 0;\n"
         "                N(a+2);\n"
         "                for(o = Y(i)-1; o<Y(j); ++o)\n"
         "                    puts(l[o]);\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'A':\n"
         "                y = r++;\n"
         "                strcpy(l[y], a+2);\n"
         "                x = c[y] = strlen(a+2);\n"
         "                ++x;\n"
         "                ++y;\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'i':\n"
         "                D();\n"
         "                --y;\n"
         "                x=X(0);\n"
         "                // Commands i and r are very similar -> fall through\n"
         "                // from i to r after moving rows down and setting\n"
         "                // position at end of line:\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'r':\n"
         "                strcpy(*L+x-1, a+2);\n"
         "                *C = strlen(*L);\n"
         "                x = 1;\n"
         "                ++y > r && ++r;\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'I':\n"
         "                o = strlen(a+2);\n"
         "                memmove(*L+x+o-1, *L+x-1, *C-x+1);\n"
         "                *C += o;\n"
         "                memcpy(*L+x-1, a+2, o);\n"
         "                x += o;\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'd':\n"
         "                **L ? **L = *C = 0, x = 1 : U();\n"
         "                y = y>r ? r : y;\n"
         "                B;\n"
         "\n"
         "            A 'j':\n"
         "                y<r && U();\n"
         "        }\n"
         "    }\n"
         "}\n";);
}
```

This produces

> ```c
> main(){printf("Hello, World!");}
> ```

> ```c
> #define max(x,y)x>y?x:y
> #define I(x)scanf("%d",&x)
> a;b;main(){I(a);I(b);printf("\" max \": %d\n",max(a,b));}
> ```

> ```c
> x[10];*c;i;main(){int _e;for(;scanf("%d",&x)>0&&++_e;);for(c=x+_e;c-->x;i=100/ *x,printf("%d ",i- --_e));}
> ```

> ```c
> #define P printf(
> #define A case
> #define B break
> #define L(i,e,t,f,s)for(o=i;o e;){strcpy(l[o t],l[o f]);c[o t]=c[s o];}
> #define R(m,o){return b<1|b>m?m o:b;}
> #define N(f)sscanf(f,"%d,%d",&i,&j)||sscanf(f,",%d",&j)
> r,i,j,o,z,c[999],*C,x=1,y=1;char a[999],l[999][999],(*L)[999];D(){L(r,>y,,-1,--)r++?strcpy(l[o],l[o-1]+--x),c[o-1]=x,l[o-1][x]=0:0;c[y++]=strlen(l[o]);x=1;}U(){strcat(*L,l[y]);*C=strlen(*L);L(y+1,<r,-1,,++)--r;*l[r]=c[r]=0;}X(b)R(c[y-1],+1)Y(b)R(r,)main(){for(;;){z=i=y;L=l+--z;C=c+z;j=x;!r||y/r&&x>*C?P"end> "):P"%d,%d> ",y,x);scanf("%[^\n]%*c",a)?a[2]*=!!a[1],N(a)?y=Y(i+(i<0|*a=='+')*y),x=X(j+(j<0||strchr(a+1,'+'))*x):0:(*a=D(),scanf("%*c"));switch(*a){A'e':y=r;x=c[r-1]+1;B;A'b':y=1;x=1;B;A'L':for(o=y-4;++o<y+2;)o<0^o<r&&P"%c%s\n",o^z?' ' :'>',l[o]);for(o=x+1;--o;)P" ");P"^\n");B;A'l':puts(*L);B;A'p':i=1;j=0;N(a+2);for(o=Y(i)-1;o<Y(j);++o)puts(l[o]);B;A'A':y=r++;strcpy(l[y],a+2);x=c[y]=strlen(a+2);++x;++y;B;A'i':D();--y;x=X(0);A'r':strcpy(*L+x-1,a+2);*C=strlen(*L);x=1;++y>r&&++r;B;A'I':o=strlen(a+2);memmove(*L+x+o-1,*L+x-1,*C-x+1);*C+=o;memcpy(*L+x-1,a+2,o);x+=o;B;A'd':**L?**L=*C=0,x=1:U();y=y>r?r:y;B;A'j':y<r&&U();}}}
> ```

### Limitation

This breaks definitions such as

```c
#define A (x)
```

by removing the space that separates the name from expansion, giving

```c
#define A(x)
```

with an entirely different meaning.  This case is absent from the test sets, so I'm not going to address it.

I suspect I might be able to produce a shorter version with a multi-pass in-place conversion - I might try that next week.

Comment: You can save one byte by removing the `=` at the end of the definition of `O` and change the space that follows each call to `O` into a `=`.

Comment: This is great ;) About the "limitation", see also my comment on the question itself -- detecting **this** would add just too much complexity.

Comment: @Zachary - thanks for that - I forgot when I changed the general code to ASCII-specific that `O'\\'` and `O' '` both acquired a space.

Comment: [464 bytes](https://tio.run/##TVFNj5tADL3zK1gqRTYM2jQkWoXRiEsr9VIhcUgPmz0kfIRBWSAz7KWQ357aRNkuEiO/N372sycPT3l@u30rykq3pZv6lyBwHihzwSi/DwL8pHaQI2h7OLcf7xROuVLbDTp5fTB@L/yLMMKKQRaAo7a2P@QlGExOgLEJ1y/T5PehSUy4XSWQKqsMhtGacLRNnkySKhMXkCEfIlUUHElY0n@CHBDllfAIwFezjpqvSJWJY3yMSVMgAmVR7lh1BmQWfl9K7AM1Z8orlRqZS6xKiRD3PgbjmmUNF3@4zjBpvnoeuEa0EUXMVkRz71SRpIGBlsSXRGgiCtiBxcViR6NPk1Vq/bIg8Xo1AYNopjbInF2w0tIM0Spekr7@srjsvjjNjU7szbD1Oh54UaKJyVe0IWwfEzG5nH19PuiPn79TyLuixJHfyNWvb4qh6F6t/lt2lavfZK@0vKhO0jSy/xgsdFTCeT/olro6cwnvjtxx33qOy5/HR290O1Sw936V53Mn3D@dORdPew@l@/zs1vp/9pVCYq@3fw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, <s>250+3 (-00n)</s>, 167+1 (-p) bytes

```
$_.=<>while s/\\
//;s,(//.*)|(("|')(\\.|.)*?\3)|/?[^"'/]+,$1|$2?$2:$&=~s@(\S?)\K\s+(?=(.?))@"$1$2"=~/\w\w|\+\+|--|\/\*/&&$"@ger,ge;$d++&&$l+/^#/&&s/^/
/,$l=/^#/m if/./
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HYlBT4MwGEDv/RVN17CWQr8M40XGyt2jRz8xRupo0gGhLJhY99NF9F1eXt5oJ3@/rvxVV8fT0jlvaQBEAlCGTADoVEYhWNxLgaijlqnBOxnBPDdsDy8q44fIC8OLB55Ut1ALfDISHzEoYSqhjZQ14wdesOoGuOASUaGKeR4RMIUk4aw@2yk725K3Sm3tFTS7bQRogEDGffXXF@o@QMO6fpZk5/p3f20tPYa5dYPuTsT1M728uV5I8kXoxnidg2Cd9X6gAHTu7GQR2XbYvyQtyffPMM5u6MOaj78)

Comment: Yes I just put a non-optimal solution. I've just added the tio link, I will look to golf it when i have time.

Comment: preprocessor directive are on their own line when are placed before code, as in the test cases however if it's required i will add change

Comment: fixed see update

Answer (score 2):

## C,  <s>705</s>   <s>663</s>  640 bytes

*Thanks to @Zacharý for golfing 40 bytes and thanks to @Nahuel Fouilleul for golfing 23 bytes!*

```
#define A(x)(x>47&x<58|x>64&x<91|x>96&x<123)
#define K if(*C==47&(C[1]==47|p==47)){if(p==47)--G;for(c=1;c;*C++-92||c++)*C-10||--c;if(d)p=*G++=10,--d;
#define D if(!d&*C==35){d=1;if(p&p-10)p=*G++=10;}
#define S K}if((A(p)&A(*C))|(p==*C&l==43|p==45)|p==47&*C==42|p==95&(A(*C)|*C==95)|*C==95&(A(p)|p==95))p=*G++=32;}
#define W*C<33|*C==92
#define F{for(;W;C++)
c,d,e,p,l;g(char*C,char*G)F;for(;*C;*C>32&&*C-34&&*C-39&&(p=*G++=*C),*C-34&&*C-39&&C++){l=e=0;if(*C==34)l=34;if(*C==39)l=39;if(l)for(*G++=l,p=*G++=*++C;*C++-l|e%2;e=*(C-1)-92?0:e+1)p=*G++=*C;K}D if(d){if(W)F{*C-92||++d;*C-10||--d;if(!d){p=*G++=10;goto E;}}S}else{if(W)F;S}E:D}*G=0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVdtb9pKFv7OrzjlKsTjlw2QpLvgmCqX3larRlerra7ailLJsQcwNR5rbBoI8Nu7z4yNA8HZW9pgz5k5b895GwJnGgQ/f/4W8kmUcLo1VsxYDa7@2VrdXP9ruxq8vsJbr4O33mu8dbqXrLE//IGiiWEOPQ/HjeGoM1Zv21R9M7bBXvHqOO/diZBG4HXcwDWHluX0utttYFnMHDqd9nbrOIGL4yFLPfO9ZXmdtu04oVspeqsUvQpbStflNduEkKTEt1KwPzG5u4rjI33Y4YRxa6SsdQsjGdsqc8xhK4ZRl9rKa1YYq@VeddWid90y9PGtovWu98@WllScYHuNl90DjZ/M4c3lZXG8W1HfbZTn7icXXrNGYIc2t1M7dqdGMPOlObT14z17pxECOPg/uOy2YJJzeVU8eq2WUWqEYfbxjpK7iT3utd0yGJdXLMZXteypZU8tY6aUaEGxvZdoWcMiJvGWn3Vd7pkGgsIQojftPrc6rFLtftjpQIQ6tp/Yuw1sUJG0rNCtIhm6OlZs8xSWqcgF/eHudh93PM54ye1@3P3Rf7sz38P03c/foiSIlyGnmywPI/GP2aBxSJJRMlW0KMlp4UeJwRqbBuGj8KNMBqOrdu/12H2ihTzL98Qn6v1yMuq0u1flyYdZFHMyJlOeZwb2bFKbNikbEsb0GfWBAYGfG9BjKxGsFDktKErVnpTC0nxiNM@yZrWx@3lxQWKS84SWGQ9pskyCPBJJdvGdrx@EDLN@lTD/2UuoKLcU@Bmvlr/TveT@90YDMmMh0owQVApEugZEJMVDRsv0wYfQi1A8JPqNfMkpixZRDAicARAMpKgk3hmRTdym3CYAkDH6WvmtRBvCi1wSxF220UCkayMeCcrHNqnnZMxcCjTBC0YZibFLO22e9JMpB@48@K4lKeMuAhEvF0lGUfayRf81FrZgtCHJ86VM6P6ms70fLOgNLWBIn@73GrRs5bcSnywXXEaBH1OUpMtcaUg4DwF4/hAFCPNC/ODkJ2EBMTBbLLBiT@D/aUwYZVngJxMDUDTPQvssRBxbAKg1Z7TdHu6We3NWOCvEQpvR6/WKMDxE@Yy4H8w0CX5nZCQipyzlQTSJeAiwZ2IZh3TPiSdiOZ0xJcmPM4HUCWIVtWawlJLD2lgZmAoYzmXWJMO809pCP/dtMod6oc/EPJnmM2ZrUUmJBZJ2whFLn2kAskD6OQz74cvIv4951pA2wcm5TcKmRxvxhM1jJdimldexaY2W29Al5JdbsX6WC5jD9KurwdBIaxBUDtJEApu9I3hmsDUVWaSKoPG2quU7A1YM1jbZ5ECl4xQFKC0LkX/KvCLvnM7YcpwVU7aqhbfak0ersddGlrTLbjBaW9aYPCUB2GgJrNhaKad2zyxepjb5acqTUCXWEm9yIbKc0MMOY9H4q7K77A7mnbJgvReOmFQ6gY5buri24NqNLFy0SY0FteE4smSLR1JZGxSP9t7ARMiFH0ePvEIuQ8miFeTUJj9DBa0an417huKBx4ABsjus8aUgQR/S9Khz6oHjMoJsvPIfXGrypip@bEQJNBVaH5WSo2SMkpAD9HzGqTZJ7SNJOu/mRc7yib@Mc2RfvORoGJPKJSBeMT3C@wh/a7ci3WEZkwWwHp@ICuYAxAPSHKRV2ZBL/SlSMM37FemVVNW8vpDUatGKBghXtac@b9CJm8iBATXZ0UZfbejGgC3UBeqDHatCTELyCyzgW1GAxjJT6aS7B6G@HzhKIznPdYsq6lQPu4OZoxtN82z07WsyPjMDKPNZ48gWnRb7PoYmP0UHTPKsaKjf962X@1nEZf@Ze/6oOybTo1evfNzc7FPBz7opZM581IgulFJl/zkTjgfL2M853HrAKcy2KMESqXrUqpuS41T0gzePJPyJ/nREKExdI5xfjAgxNqKbNm3J9D3v3DpnZNL6lEF9EBUwfTbmimmumLa6TGfS8FUBKm7Fvjpl77dPsHgaYRxJtC4QsYtAq7DG2l/dFZ5x6mnDJVgXKHo9zQb16PXJgF8wGv3QroKPsDM6zK8MUyWYGeYBUJsjObd0zs/7J14pDKV7Ql4VnQbtAkB1Tvd/dxvPpd@/IL1TL/3XhN7VCFUNSqgG4Fy56JOCbmhtdd36gAvE@Bu@dT2rCg3Osq8JakZ8e0QKneNfn84H53pI7Ft0nbaV1XHRYMQLeiAaHeGUHXTUad1OjbdxjbfIqOxpTvyNgLRGQFQP9rwYIs/JKDWr@39gQL0xB0iImy/GnGn86wHRdr@AaY3lty/lpmWd8lczf41pVm9vkcDrg/lef86yVnXE9S8ZHdUYjTI95XWcGoEr77PRrjmM9jAsOkFWjkepL@qYxOvDu/HEj2NMWakuiHVC9O0qUvcT8ONXhlQ9uvoxoC9g@s7H8/xwvh4Ox3L8Ei4TmHlqaqlm1j8BQtYAUQbJvLNW6kpTD3/tZegXWgUihNmsi9qy5C8F6981Noq/S48FX6jBpr2whPJj7w9@2KIl1LtkeSRqZT0DBF2o1uV6/hqfwhqfTPwCeKO/vQLedjH0Omh0f9Ulpyqz9UCCSeLIr2X@vK5ciyZ7pGPXKL53/wM)

Comment: Can `for(;W;C++){}` become `for(;W;C++);`?

Comment: @Zacharý that was never asked for. It's a toool for the very last step: remove redundant whitespace and comments.

Comment: I was referring to his code, not the challenge.

Comment: @Zacharý haha I see ... weird when code and input are the same language ;)

Comment: Would this work for 665 bytes? https://goo.gl/E6tk8V

Comment: Already been hopelessly outgolfed in C though

Comment: -23 bytes, && and || by & and | where possible,when no side effect [tio](https://tio.run/##VVFBTsMwELzziiKE5bVjqYkTIDUpqkLbQ4899IA4INstlSIaAYdKsd9e1k4bQIrsXWd2ZuzRYqf16XRj7Hb/YUczegR6nOb35PhYPLjj9C7HqkyxKu@wSjMJVxfwarTfUlZXFcJp/ZK@hsq1YQXo8F9fCrFU28Mn1VWqtGI156LMnNOcA6tFOnZOCK0QbqCt2JLzKh0nQhg1CD0HoWtDgpYsoDPIFOhJi@O/Q8oPE@vRyiOCzmgLZIYmAVyww2rSoCkZXRbQm428eRaasiA0wl04K4vLTiJTj4CLosz@KG5Y/ShlD8@G00UXbq42Cm8NVzoxiU3apFE7qt/fPlmdxG0Ji/hC@Dj4TWVG0JKQeb@VhNCzIhpL/v8JvF1T2WqszmHIHBpchrYMbRnaBoJIJGqSCyPndZ9J4@xtpmzFKIYCGNHTeGJ5CoO0WvkYhInZbmDRoYeQJOdGDUkaFbOC7jeW3eH7MJor79feNl/2PK3Wfj559myJ1v3p9AM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>479</s> <s>456</s> <s>445</s> <s>434</s> <s>502</s> 497 bytes

```python
e=enumerate
import re
u=re.sub
def f(s):
 r=()
 for l in u(r'\\\n','',s).split('\n'):
	s=p=w=0;L=[]
	for i,c in e(l):
	 if(p<1)*'//'==l[i:i+2]:l=l[:i]
	 if c in"'\""and w%2<1:
		if p in(c,0):L+=[l[s:i+1]];s=i+1
		p=[0,c][p<1]
	 w=[0,w+1]['\\'==c]
	r+=L+[l[s:]],
 S=''
 for l in r:s=''.join([u('. .',R,u('. .',R,u('\s+',' ',x))).strip(),x][i%2]for i,x in e(l));S+=['%s','\n%s\n'][s[:1]=='#']%s
 print u('\n\n','\n',S).strip()
def R(m):g=m.group(0);f=g[::2];return[f,g][f.isalnum()or f in'++ -- /*']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVhdb5tIF74uv@LUVQoYnNjR3hRCqm73plK0erXVSq0wXWE8xONiBs1ADWn72/s@M9iuHZPd5sLAMOfrOec8Z0jV1StRXv/4wSJWNhsm05pZfFMJWZNkVhNJdqmahbVkOeWOcgOLZOS4FuVCUkG8pMaR9nw@L23ftn3lXqqq4LVjYwGbn6moirbRNLyL4sR6poW4n2kx5hT6PfHcqW5m7ti@urKjqIh5wL3rJChwG/DEbCAtMLLno1FaLml7cX0zg@QzvKjwwsn8qRvceVFcxArCsyQJVYQrtlRRPPWzJIYFrWqrH7fYEcNjWMuwKL3ozjOiSeJb9D6y7aPgZKCwcLkWsBM3jn1Jl7b/l39yN1ceYifbb10X4deSV47rt0nML66TPuJ2H7Ebvoej9oWCxLy8UEApiVUczJIosl/YyYWyqJK8rEkrLg2q@uf9QbHJxF/Oxg3uo83lvRRN5UzdMI/u4yC4TkLJ6kaWce7fJ3F@yVVaIK2OCzdyOGF7Hk0mdDW2kx@5I0ej0Qvo4yWjTdo6rU@dS3OL8NfSLXX0GteAOmu/653TuqSytMyd0cVy5NPL1rXS0FqEdHVF60bVlFLJ2LJgSlEmNhtW1v5Opf5bsCxtFKMtI2h5bm1SIOtaX82Gd07qhru7xe7OoAFr85F2keajgC6W8xKmtcepTwuAan1HJK5lmc2W1UfWxrNpEo6zkIenZjS8/7BePfLjhI8jQuhTevmSPA/b3J8bM4qAh6eFUZOTyS21IXEszqZTuqIx8Nu7e7Ek6OI0wbZ/2JMuhtYLXmZFs2R0o@olF5erW0v7d@Jw1dTKGa1YUQgNc71iko2eUIn3Iq8Z@lKxJeVNmdVclOrqM@u2Qi5VcMjl//bOHlbeICeKHR5/p4Vk6WfLgs5CiEqZvshE1fHynqTYKmqqbQqlV0uxLc0dpZKR4htepJIA0CbNpDhovHO4T8wnlETuk3KPCkOrdkTEQxIE0L8S6j2rOqeIBdWJT/qaJy6ANwtRFisSSUjfjXsyLe9RUSuWfTaatHNXmSiaTamIq6c9Qif5wqWv1PcNLW5m3xa3GxT@Bo4EtNhbMLp13Fq9YUqepZojkBxtQRc9AK@3PGPkbMQXRpqt@mbWjYAn9yf4fzo5GqmvO0CBevH76gNAL9cufft2/Hb3bu32wQqxMW68evWqT8OW1ytiabYyS4hbkVOKmlTFMp5ztgTYK9EUS/QfsVI09ytXa0oLJWjJskJnbZQ1UqJdqdAOVqC8mkk1Imd8Z6wt0xrtNn7bs6PeU7Dyvl65vlFV7rBYNHnOkMvUNQCoDCMFjn1JJU8XoAVLoi98WvskfHrwkU/4nGjFPrXRDBQUzUIrWyFb6e5VYa67B7jjmtvQgGGQNiDoGqRcApt9ILgq@FoJxXUTWH8cOurOgRe3nU8@TWByMnHNsgQ9vj6qvL7uJrPEm0xaV/uqH6J2vxy3STRFlUx7jsjizvMS8AE0ABujYUcfrQ7q@yOPm8qntKpYudSF1eBObgQotBZ0nAvr74Pf2rW0BgTag26vHDk52AQ64S7EzkNoN7IP0Qeb9UFOJnInVsRSe5v1l@newVLITVrwB3ZATqFlQQU1aDFVmnitDyBoNA8iBgzQPXOtj/0S7KFMT/jLkGzoau7CLfvCpFn@emh@vOAlLPVWH7SRk2Lk5ZIBdBAfDRapf6LJ1N26r1mWp01Ro/qKhoEw8kNIQPwg9IDoNY134WHpDo8F6WH58HNRw5xh8WhprUcCKvHIfoUSrOrgsPRc6m7urqQeKXqsjt8e3um/12DiEWrglkbuyYtAvzDEcKuHCaq1dU9NISdLDFyDhch3Deg0SpeTYQ9Cf2PULkVp14ai@j41E@ensf34iz/Ny@RinMFY6lonvpiy2PMYSP6@0ZNd9YT6eU@9LFWcyeBReGl8ndA4oufP0xjFcq74EZtC5ypFj5hG2ZkMHgthe9YUOK0irC12YbbxEo8o1ROqHkmGXfwLG51o@BP8dLLQu9ohnR8djhw7/GZK32ic4mDm2S6NcTQ6E9B/yAqEPjhrLbTWQt9Mm66kk@oG1NJavD0XD6ZnWPwcYQxF1PWI@H2idVoLE69hhUeSZtowCdENmt5Ms9th9AJyEBecBh/6h@Qj7S4d15fCVMlWzvgIqK8net6QzezgLCqNoQzPltueaUAXAGp2/v730HqsffGE9tmw9l9TejegVBOU0AQw@S0ETwq6oc67DocTLpDjT/g1/aw7NNPnePSM@PSAEsKXABC2b20zJPYUPWSt9WYhCEY8YQeqaTQgjnX06dCbgWiLgWjNcfIwJ/5DQTWggA@Dve6HyONltJp3/S8woN/cCZAQNx@dtWvwHwbE@P0EpgOev3mqNj3vXP4w8ztMs2F/@wLujub78D7Pa4cWu19ymg84jTY9l51MBhS20Qf9MXi2Dnp42zOB2o1HaQ7qmMTd8dk4T4sCU1bqA@KQEnO64vp8Anl8ZUjN0YePAXMAM2c@VtfH8/V4OO7GL@EwgZmnp5Yms@AMCDkAxC5J4zuv1UeaYfgHD0O/QBXIEGaz7L/75C8l692Aj@K/ymPDNnqwmSg8oePYxzN@OwElDIfkRSQGdT0CBCw0GPKw/EBMy4GYxvgCeG1@ox7eaT/0ZiC6v4eKU7dZdyshJPW/D37J8HqoXXuSPbHx3ep/zcfvj/8D)

Edit: Fixed to include `- -`,`+ +`, and `/ *`